# integrate $\tan^2x \sin x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do I integrate (find the primitive to) $$ \int \tan^2 x \sin x dx$$

My approach has been to rewrite it to $$\int \frac{\sin^3 x}{\cos^2 x}dx$$ and the do the substitution $t = \tan x/2$. This works but I believe there's an easier way.

(I know that $0 < x < \pi/2$)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\cos x = t$ , then the integral reduces to :

$$\int \frac{\sin^3 x}{\cos^2 x} \, dx = \int \frac{-(1-t^2)}{t^2} \, dt.$$

This can easily be solved.

Comment: shouldn't it be -(1-t)^2/t^2?

Comment: Sin^2 t = 1 - cos^2 t = 1- t^2

Comment: @user150264 Hi there, and welcome to MSE! I've edited your answer to include the appropriate mathjax commands to render your equations. I encourage you to study what I did and learn to use our site's wonderful latex capabilities for yourself.

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Comment: @david how to change my current name to my real name?  I'm using the android app.

Answer (score 6):

**HINT :**
$$
\int \tan^2 x \sin x\ dx=-\int (\sec^2 x-1)\ d(\cos x).
$$